# MapController Alloc Init & ViewController alloc init Resulting in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I Have a very long view controller.m which I'm trying to split into separate files to keep it organised. 
I know I can create separate .m .h files and separate them but in doing so I am ending up in loops (which I Understand since the MapController.m is initialising the viewcontroller again causing viewDidLoad to be triggered and repeat.

I have a Map I want to create in my `MapController.m`

```
-(void)setMapSettings{
    NSLog(@"test");
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    SKMapView *mapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f,  CGRectGetWidth(viewController.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(viewController.view.frame) )];

}
```

I want to add the above `SKMapView` to a `UIView` called `mapViewContainer` in my `viewController.h`

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mapsViewController = [[MapController alloc] init];
    [mapsViewController setMapSettings];
}
```

Doing this creates a loop resulting in a crash. I know the answer is probably dead simple and I'm just being stupid, but I've spent hours finding a solution and I can't figure it out. Any idea's how I'm suppose to be able to do the above without looping, and without initialising the map views I require all in the ViewController.m?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are splitting the view controller by taking out code from it, but as far as I understand this has resulted in creating a second viewcontroller (either this, or "MapController" isn't the right naming).

Anyways, as you already mentioned the crash is definitely caused by that alloc/init loop: you should reengineer your code to have just one of the two objects instantiating the other.

(please bear in mind that if you are doing that to access one object from the other, you're doing it wrong: alloc/init creates a *new* instance of that class every time it is called, it does not give you a pointer to an existing one)